# final (1).jpg An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later. please help me to solve this error

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzgkY.png)
this is the screenshot. when I upload an image in media file I get error, please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it can appear because of write permission on the uploads folder in your host.